# Setting block size for MKL LAPACK

Tags: c, fortran, intel, lapack, hpc

is it possible to change the block size used by LAPACK algorithms, when working with Intel MKL? The values are retrieved from ilaenv method, but it is possible to overwrite it somehow? For example, if I want to find an optimal block size for my algorithm?
I know that the reference implementation of MKL has some additional ilaenv implementation, used for testing.

Comment: Why would you want to change the block size? These are (usually) determined in a way that they optimally utilize the caches of your CPU. Changing the block size will probably be detrimental on the performance...

Comment: I want to make some experiments and measure the performance for different sizes.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the [ATLAS project](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/), then.

Comment: BLIS makes these settings quite easy to change and the compile time is 1000x less than ATLAS. https://github.com/flame/blis

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!